# $base_path is not added to AJAX URL request in login form

Tags: ajax, uri

I have a D7 site in a subfolder, and would like for AJAX requests to find the correct docroot folder.

When trying to login from `localhost/mysite/user`, AJAX sends a request to `localhost/system/ajax`. I've read that you can use the global variable `$base_path` for this, so I gave it a try, still the same error. I've checked in Firebug and indeed `Drupal.settings.basePath` does have the correct path. In settings.php is it written like this `$base_path = '/mysite/';`.

This made me wonder if the JS logic does not include the `$base_path` value by default and what would be a correct way to add this in. The site is tracked in Git, so I've also experimented with Apache configurations, such as [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse), and ReWrite rules in order to prevent having to push changes that would risk breaking the site on the remote server.

I'm new to Drupal and not so experienced with Apache directives, any help here would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took suggestion from [Artur](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1691/artur), problem solved by defining two domains in hosts file. One for the development environment and the other as a backup of the production environment. Then it was a case of setting up virtual hosts like this in `httpd.conf` (example for the development environment):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.project.devel
    ServerAlias project.devel *.project.devel
    DocumentRoot /www/mysite/devel/docroot/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
</VirtualHost>
```

Login also worked even when domain was removed from the English language row in the `languages` table in the Drupal database. `$base_url` and `$base_path` also were commented out in `settings.php`, not needed with fake domains.

Answer (score 0):

First off, in the settings.php file you should have an example of `http://www.example.com` and a comment there, saying that you should not append a trailing slash.
Next, in your case looks like `http://localhost` would be the correct value of $base_url, **if any** - try hashing out $base_url line to see if the site is fine without it - as it might be.

Comment: Hi, I'm confused, is it the same problem that's referred above? To state is very shortly: `$base_path` is not included in AJAX requests when a form, such as a login form is submitted.

Comment: Assuming `mysite` is at the root of htdocs, you could try `$base_url = 'http://localhost/mysite';` I prefer to establish a fake domain such as `mysite.localhost.com` - (http://www.codingcereal.com/2011/05/setting-up-multiple-subdomains-in-your-localhost-using-xampp/). Then, I'm usually fine with base_url commented out. Just give it a try - the AJAX requests should point to correct location.

Comment: `$base_url` is set to `http://localhost/mysite` and `$base_path` is set to `/mysite/` assuming `$base_url` and `$base_path` are not the same thing, correct? Or is the formatting wrong? Should a path start with the disk-mount's root folder? See [reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals). Because `Drupal.settings.basePath` is available, I assume that I must supply the global `$base_path` a value as well.

Comment: I will have a look into the suggestion you mentioned, I thought there would be some way that Drupal would add a base when the relevant variables are added to settings.php or if there is a Drupal way of injecting the base information somewhere in the codebase.